# Crystal Reports 2008 - why are my database reports so sluggish (includes all steps tried)

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

We've recently started using Crystal Reports 2008 to fulfill wild dreams of automated processes, linking multiple data sources, canned reports for all.

But, Crystal Reports is being intolerably slow when querying our SQL Server databases.

-

**Preliminary (to be expanded on below)**

I checked the "Performance Information" and most of the delay is due to *Read Database Records*

- A stripped-down version of a query (10,000 results) takes about 30s to redisplay results if I add in one of our fields.
- A less stripped-down version of a query (20,000 results) takes about 1m30s
- The actual query has about 60,000 results and takes over 8 minutes to display

-

**System & Settings**

1. Under "Report Options...", *Save Data with Report* is unchecked.
2. Under "Options...", *Verify When Database Driver Upgraded* is unchecked (was recommended on another forum)
3. Windows 7, 4GB ram, 64 Bit system
4. When the program grays out, I run *Task Manager*, CR does not seem to take up any more memory and CPU usage is only a few percent.

-

**The Database itself**

1. Connection is OLE DB
2. Stored Procedures are...off the table (*cricket noises). Our department has certain restrictions on database (read-only)
3. The query has been optimized as much as possible (only one join), just using 6 fields
4. All of the WHERE criteria (3 in total) are in the query
5. Besides the join/one WHERE criteria, the bulk of the data is from a View

-

Are there other options/settings that could speed up this process? It seems that taking 8 minutes for 60,000 records doesn't speak well for how effectively CR can be used.

Comment: *"Besides the join/one WHERE criteria, the bulk of the data is from a View"* - this means that the underlying query is almost certainly **more** than just one join. Can you try running your existing query on your report machine in SSMS? If so, how long does it take? Can you look at the view definition in SSMS? If so, can your query be further trimmed down? Can you use a native driver instead of OLE DB to connect to SQLServer?

Comment: Can you post the report or at least the query ?